# A Concave function

Tags: calculus

Part of a solution to a problem I had said that: for a concave function $f(x)$

$$ f(x) - x f'(x) > 0 $$

In calculus when we learned concave it was in respect to concave up or concave down and looked at the second derivative, but none of that is here; what other properties of a concave function are they using here?

Comment: For a function $ f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, concave means that the straight line drawn from any two points on the graph of $f$ is below the function $f$. You probably think of this as concave down.

Comment: How can we prove this?  I'm stuck sorry,
$$ f(x_2) - f(x_1) > (x_2-x_1)f'(x) $$
$$ > (x_2-x_1) \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} = f(x_2)-f(x_1) $$